# Install Heroku CLI on Mac with Bash Termimal

Tags: heroku-cli

I'm trying to follow this guide and install Heroku CLI on my Mac.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install

When I typed

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

The terminal returns

```
bash: brew: command not found
```

What should I do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are u already install brew on your system?
if not try read this :

https://brew.sh/

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)
```

paste that in a macOS Terminal or Linux shell prompt.

after install brew, try again install heroku cli

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Answer (score 4):

just use `brew install heroku/brew/heroku`

Answer (score 1):

After installing brew as suggested by Lussac, you need to enter a password. It is the password that you use to log into your computer.

You won't see anything when you type your password for security purposes. Just press enter!

Comment: This answer was really unnecessary. It's not even an answer, and should have been a comment

Comment: It might be unnecessary for you but might help others - be it an answer or comment!